# How to fix "PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG: command not found" error?

Tags: configure

I have Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit system. Recently when I try to to compile by running `./autogen.sh` and `./configure` I get

```
 PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG: command not found
```

error. I have `libtool` installed. I have three aclocal files in `usr/share/` like `alocal`, `aclocal-1.13` and `aclocal-1.4`

How can I fix that alocal error?

EDIT:

Some time ago I compiled latest version of automake from source and installed it because a source code needed recent version of automake to run configure process. 
Since then whenever I run standard `./autogen` and `/configure` commands in source directory to generate `makefile` I get

```
  PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG: command not found
```

error

```
  find /usr -name "pkg.m4"
```

gives me

```
  /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
```

and

```
  aclocal --print-ac-dir
```

gives me

```
  /usr/local/share/aclocal
```

Comment: is the `pkg-config` package installed? does the file `/usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4` exist on your system?

Comment: What are you trying to compile?

Comment: @steeldriver
`find /usr -name "pkg.m4"` gives me `/usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4`

Comment: @Jobin
I am trying to compile this: https://codeload.github.com/blazt/submarine/zip/master

Comment: What does `aclocal --print-ac-dir` say?

Comment: @steeldriver
it's `/usr/local/share/aclocal`

Comment: So the disconnect appears to be that your `pkg.m4` macro file is in `/usr/share` but for some reason aclocal is looking in `/usr/local/share`. It's difficult to suggest the best fix without knowing how you got in that situation - did you install a local (non-standard) version of `automake` maybe?

Comment: @steeldriver
Yes, I think so, but I don't remember when. I reinstalled `pkg-config` but it didn't fix it. You helped me pinpoint the problem, Thank you.

Comment: You could try setting (or exporting) the `ACLOCAL_PATH` environment variable e.g. `ACLOCAL_PATH=/usr/share/aclocal` ./autogen.sh` or `export ACLOCAL_PATH=/usr/share/aclocal ; ./autogen.sh ; ./configure` - see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Macro-Search-Path.html)

Comment: @steeldriver
It works. Would you post it as an answer? It might be helpful to readers.

Comment: please, add all the information of the comments to your question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG` variable refers to a macro `pkg.m4` that is provided as part of the pkg-config package, so the first thing to check is that pkg-config is installed and that the macro file is in the default location (and is readable, of course)

```
dpkg -l pkg-config

ls -l /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
```

If that checks out, then the question becomes why is `aclocal` not finding it? You can check where `aclocal` is configured to look for third-party m4 files using the `--print-ac-dir` switch i.e.

```
aclocal --print-ac-dir
```

If that's not the same as the location above, it suggests there is a non-standard version of automake on your system - if you can't resolve that, then a possible workaround is to set or export the `ACLOCAL_PATH` environment variable before running the autogen.sh script e.g.

```
ACLOCAL_PATH=/usr/share/aclocal ./autogen.sh
```

or

```
export ACLOCAL_PATH=/usr/share/aclocal
./autogen.sh
./configure
```

See the [macro search path](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Macro-Search-Path.html#Macro-Search-Path) section of the GNU automake manual.

Comment: Or, `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG` could come from a typo in a variable assignment, e.g. `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG<space>=...` instead of `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG=...`. `grep "PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG "` on your files.