# How can I fix library conflicts during compilation stemmed from manually installed packages from source code?

Tags: compiling, libraries

I have Ubuntu 14.04 upgraded from 12.04 making dist-upgrades. I did many manual installations such as **ffmpeg**, **libglib** and so on, in the past.  I have a nice custom distro now, it works well but I have problems while trying to compile applications. The errors I got taught me lots, I found how to deal with linker errors, I list some of them below:

[how-can-i-guide-compiler-to-use-a-certain-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174207/how-can-i-guide-compiler-to-use-a-certain-library)

[how-to-fix-pkg-prog-pkg-config-command-not-found-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468661/how-to-fix-pkg-prog-pkg-config-command-not-found-error)

[pkg-config-modversion-glib-2-0-reports-older-version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488187/pkg-config-modversion-glib-2-0-reports-older-version)

[how-to-fix-libgmodule-2-0-so-0-could-not-read-symbols-invalid-operation-erro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442921/how-to-fix-libgmodule-2-0-so-0-could-not-read-symbols-invalid-operation-erro)

[multiple-ffmpeg-library-paths-how-can-exclude-older-ffmpeg-installations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141195/multiple-ffmpeg-library-paths-how-can-exclude-older-ffmpeg-installations)

[how-can-i-use-a-particular-library-while-compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531755/how-can-i-use-a-particular-library-while-compiling)

I come to such a point that even I can get errors while compiling native Ubuntu applications such as **unity** (I want to embed **unity launcher** into **cairo dock** [unity launcher in cairo dock](http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Cairo-Dock%20and%20Unity&lang=en))

How can I fix those library conflicts? I lost manually  compiled application's directories so I have no chance to run `make uninstall`.

I am fed up with adjusting library paths.
What do you suggest me in this position?

Comment: Hopefully, the manual installations you did were in the `/usr/local` prefix. You could try removing everything in the `bin`, `lib`, etc. folders. (Don't remove the folders themselves.)

Comment: Build packages of the versions you want to install. You can probably use something like `checkinstall` to simplify things, but this way you can avoid at least side conflicts and use them like the official packages.

Comment: @saiarcot895
Thank you for suggestion but I didn't get what you meant. If I remove everything in those directories how can I reinstall them?

Comment: @kenn: FFMpeg is in the repos and is now `avconv` in Trusty and `libglib` is in the `libglib2.0-0` package, with development headers in `libglib2.0-dev`. There's a good chance that the packages and libraries you want are in the main repos and that you don't need to compile them. As you just discovered, if you decide to compile your own version and have it **not** managed by `apt`/`dpkg`, you will have to recompile it as library versions and SONAMEs change.

Comment: @saiarcot895
I followed this guide to install ffmpeg but it didn't fix library conflict https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu Then I used this repo https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg, unfortunately the result is the same.
Somehow linker uses old libraries. Here is the issue I got while compiling `Simple Screen Recorder` https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/issues/215

Comment: @kenn: Did you remove everything under `/usr/local`? (excluding the main folders)

Comment: @saiarcot895
No, I didn't remove anything. Everything? all of the files in it? Won't my system crash?

Comment: @kenn: No, it won't. Some applications that you compiled yourself probably won't run, but all official packages should keep working.

Comment: I have `bandwidthd  etc    HTS-2.2beta  lib      man     rvm   share  src bin         games  include      libexec  nagios  sbin  SPTK   var` in `/usr/local`

Comment: Don't remove the `bin`, `etc`, `games`, `include`, `lib`, `man`, `sbin`, `share`, or `src` folders; rather remove the files within them. You can (probably) keep any of the other folders and the files within them.

Comment: @saiarcot895
Thank you for info, I didn't know that. I ll try it tomorrow and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @kenn: See my post at https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/issues/215.

Comment: @saiarcot895 
Your solution works. Thank to you I could compile `Simple Screen Recorder` Would you please post it as an answer? It might be helpful to others.

Comment: @kenn: Will do. There was another thing I realized just now regarding linking that I'll post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here was the existence of libraries and includes in `/usr/local` that were compiled in Precise (12.04).

When searching for the development headers specified by `#include`, `gcc` and `g++` have `/usr/local/include` higher on the list than `/usr/include`. Therefore, if you have a library's dev headers in  both `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/include`, then the one in `/usr/local/include` will be used, **regardless of the version**. While this may have been fine in Precise, since the libraries that were locally compiled were likely newer versions, this wouldn't be fine in Trusty, when the system version of the library would be of a equal or newer version of the library you installed. In addition, as system libraries changed, the SONAMEs would have changed, and locally-compiled libraries would have to be recompiled. Therefore, `gcc`/`g++` would use the older version and may complain about missing symbols and/or linking errors.

If a library is present in the main repos, it is generally recommended to use that library instead of compiling it by yourself (unless you **need** a newer version of a library for either development or to fix a bug); that way, when you upgrade your system, that library is updated as well, and recompiled to link correctly with the other libraries.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I simply renamed `usr/local` to `/usr/local.old` and it did the trick.

Comment: **WARNING** renaming `/usr/local` folder to `/usr/local.old` works but it fails to boot. I used live USB to rename `/usr/local.old/` back